# Can someone explain why こと is being used in this sentence?

Tags: sentence

私が彼について言ったことは、彼の弟にについても当てはまる. I don't know the grammatical explanation for the use of 'koto' in this sentence

Comment: Just a nominalizer, https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/nominalizers-koto-and-no/

Answer (score 1):

This こと is "thing", a word that refers to an abstract/intangible thing (fact, statement, etc). It is modified by a relative clause (私が彼について言った).

> 私が彼について言った**こと**
> the **thing** that I said regarding him
> what I said with regard to him
>
> 私が彼について言った**こと**は、彼の弟にについても当てはまる。
> The **thing** I said regarding him also applies to his brother.
> What I said about him is also true about his brother.